# How to make html file using java where background will gradually changing?

Tags: java, html, background

I need to create html file using java, and create inside this file table with colors that gradually changing from white to black, like at the picture:

[image: html file]

I just need ideas how I can increase color value from #000000 to #FFFFFF using java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int step = 1;

for (int i = 255; i >= 0; i-=step) {
    String hex = Integer.toString(i, 16).toUpperCase();
    hex = hex + hex + hex;
    //output hex String
}
```

See [Integer.toString(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29) for decimal to hexadecimal conversion
Note that you have to go from `R = G = B = 255` to `R = G = B = 0` to get the gradient as shown in the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.format()` function to generate hexadecimal codes of colors and then output them to a file, console, or whatever you like.

```
public static void generateGrayscale() {

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        String color = String.format("%02X%02X%02X", i, i, i);
        s.append(String.format("<tr><td style='background-color:%s'></td>", color));
    }

    System.out.println(s);
}
```